# Deploy Angular as UI and Asp.Net to the same AppService Azure

Tags: asp.net, angular, azure, deployment

I am trying to deploy Angular as UI and Asp.Net to the same app service in Azure. The issue is that the Angular project does not display on the website. I have already defined the Physical Path to the angular project but it displays this error on the website. If I am only deploying the Angular app it displays as it should on the website but as soon as I publish the Asp.Net application to it, it returns an error on the website.

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try following the steps, it may help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59987366/8070068

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deploy angular app and web API in same azure app service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58638331/how-to-deploy-angular-app-and-web-api-in-same-azure-app-service)

Answer (score 0):

Before deploying the website, kindly **configure** the **ISS (Internet Information Services)** which is a **dependency** with **angular** applications.

To deploy the **core .net** application with **Angular** with some **DB** connect, follow the steps mentioned in the [blog](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/01/08/angular-net-core-sql-on-azure-how-to-deploy-a-full-stack-app-to-microsoft-azure)

Document Credit: [Jason Watmore](https://github.com/cornflourblue)